# Accessing struct attribute: casting vs field name

Tags: readability, linux-kernel, attributes

I was just going over some [kernel code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rbtree_augmented.h#L104), I noticed that `rb->__rb_parent_color = (unsigned long)p | color;` is kinda wired. The first field of a struct is accessed by casting the pointer and not by using the field name.

[Here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rbtree.h#L35) is the definition of that struct, as you can see the color is the first attribute, so simply casting `(unsigned long)p` will give us the same as `rb->__rb_parent_color`. But why did the developers choose to do it this way and not using the `->`?

The only reason I can think of is compiler optimizations that are not done when using `rb->__rb_parent_color`, but find this hard to believe cause it seems like the compiler will, in both cases, calculate the same offset without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct rb_node *p` is *not* dereferenced. Read it again: this code casts the *address* to an `unsigned long`.

This is relying on the fact that object addresses are aligned such that the bottom bit (at least) of the address is guaranteed to be un-used, so it packs the colour into that bit. So `__rb_parent_color` here does not mean the parent's color: it means the parent pointer *and* its color are stored in this field.

Read the `__rb_parent` and `__rb_color` macros above to see how the field is used. (`__rb_parent` actually implies the bottom 2 bits are un-used, giving 4-byte alignment, but nothing seems to use the second bit either way.)

Comment: Now I also get the name `__rb_parent_color`. It means first is (a pointer to) the parent, then comes the color of the node itself.
Thanks.